# IBDesignable XIB throws error due to loading method

Tags: swift, xcode, xib, ibdesignable

Both of these result in code that runs correctly but using the `loadNibNamed` function results in a IB rendering error:

```
Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("myXib", owner: self, options: nil)
self.view.frame = bounds
self.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
self.addSubview(self.view)
```

with the following error for IB Designables:

[image: error]

whereas using this renders correctly in IB:

```
guard let view = loadViewFromNib(name: "myXib") else {return}
view.frame = bounds
view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
self.addSubview(view)

func loadViewFromNib(name : String) -> UIView? {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: name, bundle: bundle)
    return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
}
```

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: ...sooo what's the error?

Comment: Why does the first throw method throw an IB rendering error? Why the down vote, seems like a legit question? Even if I found a workaround.

Comment: Because we have no idea what the error is. What's your issue?

Comment: see the added image.

Comment: Have you tried to `debug selected views`?

Comment: yes, provides no further info beyond the image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `Bundle.main` when loading xibs because IB doesn't know what is your main bundle. You should always find the bundle depending on the location of some class, e.g. what is done in your second example:

```
Bundle(for: type(of: self))
```

Although using the type of the owner is also unsafe if your have more than one module in your app.

Comment: In this case would let 'bundle = Bundle(for: myXib.self)' be sufficient? Thanks!

Comment: @Zyntx if `myXib` is the name of you class then yes.